# Compiling for OpenVMS on Unix

Tags: c, gcc, openvms

Is it possible to cross-compile for OpenVMS(i64) on Unix host and just transfer the executable to OpenVMS server?  If it is possible, how do you do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No it is not possible.

It is however possible, providing the compiler is available on both Unix and OpenVMS (and many are), to develop the software on HP Unix and then copy the source to VMS and compile. Can't say I have ever done it and when I looked into it, I think the Unix was Digital Unix rather than HP Unix, so you may have to do some research there.

There is also a couple of web sites where you can compile source code for VMS...I think HP has one, and there is also the Deathrow Cluster which provides such a facility I believe.